# Name lookup bug in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ambiguity

I am pretty sure it is a bug in VS 2010, but it's always a good idea to check on SO

```
struct A{
   static int s;
}; 

struct B{ 
   static int s;
}; 

struct C : A, B{ 
   void fn(short s){ // Ambiguous access of 's' here!!!
      s = 2;               
   } 
}; 

int A::s;
int B::s;

int main(){ 
   C c;
}
```

VS gives- "error C2385: ambiguous access of 's'".

g++ and Comeau compile fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: MSVC++2008 (Professional Edition) and 2010 compile fine too. Checked on MSVC++2010 Ultimate

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: My VS2010 (Express Edition :) gives error.

Comment: I thought that all VS2010 editions are use the same version of the compiler.

Comment: @Kirill: I thought that too.  Not good!

Comment: @j_random_hacker, @Kirill: SO do I, and I still do. I know for a fact that name lookup in MSVC is affected by compiler settings, for instance for-scope name lookup. Therefore this bug may be settings-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual C++ is worried about the diamond problem- the instance member named "s" is ambiguous due to diamond-shaped inheritance. But here, it should be shadowed by the local parameter named "s", so there's nothing illegal about this code. It should compile cleanly, unless you have something weird set in your environment to make Visual C++ complain about shadowed variable names.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I think it is the Expression Edition!!, based on Prasoon's comment